# Firebird how to connect Java UDR

Tags: java, firebird

How to connect Java to UDR?

Here is the only example I found on the internet for Java UDR, but it doesn't work.

```sql
create or alter function regex_replace (
    regex varchar(60),
    str varchar(60),
    replacement varchar(60)
) returns varchar(60)
external name 'org.firebirdsql.fbjava.examples.fbjava_example.FbRegex.replace(
String, String, String)'
engine java;
```

```
SQL Error [335545001] [HY000]: Resource Exception. External engine JAVA not found [SQLState:39000, ISC error code:335545001]
Reason: External engine JAVA not found [SQLState:39000, ISC error code:335545001], error code: HY000
Reason: External engine JAVA not found [SQLState:39000, ISC error code:335545001]
Reason: External engine JAVA not found [SQLState:39000, ISC error code:335545001]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java UDRs in Firebird requires installing the [fbjava UDR engine](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/fbjava) in Firebird. And according to the error message, it is not installed in your case.

See https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/fbjava for installation instructions. Note the fbjava requires Java 8. It doesn't work on Java 9 or higher.